# Git rebase public branch

Tags: git

Step 1: I have master Branch followed by two commits, master branch $ git log master

```
34015a753b1
decde523115
```

Step 2: Then, i have one feature dedicated branch this branch created by based on master branch,  $ git checkout -b feature master & git log

```
34015a753b1
decde523115
```

Step 3 : Then i made two commits on my feature branch,

```
$ git log 

78035a743a6
42015a743a2
34015a753b1
decde523115
```

Step 4: Next my team mate made one new commits on master branch and then he pushed to remote server. $ git log master

```
24315a753b1
34015a753b1
decde523115
```

Step 5: suppose i want master new commit changes in my dedicated feature branch means, i have to run the command ,

```
git checkout feature
 git rebase master
```

Right ! this is normal case to rebase the dedicated branch...

So now my question is: suppose i rebased wrongly on the public branch, master onto your feature branch,

```
$ git checkout master
$ git rebase feature

$ git log
```

Now my project history changed, my master branch remote commit id is different, and my local master branch id is different because of wrong rebase. Now how to undo this wrong rebase ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use `git reflog` to find the old commit and then `git reset` the branch to it.

Comment: Thanks lot Dan ! this is perfect answer

Answer (score 1):

> Now how to undo this wrong rebase ?

Read this out and learn how to do it:

[How to move HEAD back to a previous location? (Detached head)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519665/how-to-move-head-checkout-revert-reflog-reset/34519716#34519716)

You will find there a very detailed answer on several ways to "fix" it.